# limit the total number of results a activerecord query returns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, limit

Is it possible to hard limit the number of results of pages from activerecord?

Ill know limit but using the endless scrolling jquery plugin it just only limits the number of records per page .limit(10) = 10 per page. I need to limit the total number of records so a certain user cannot get more than the first 100 results for example.

Is this possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't from Active Record, unless you put a condition that gives you something similar (ex: id). You can however control the query by looking at the page and per_page paramenter.

```
page = params[:page] || 0
per_page = 20

if page * per_page > 100
  @users = [] # You may have to make this a collection depending on what pagination gem you use
else
  @users = User.page(page).per_page(per_page)
end
```

Comment: Haven't thought about that, thanks for pointing me out to this

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is old but I ended up here and thought the answer I found elsewhere might help.  There is a limit function on ActiveRecord as of version 4 -

```
User.limit(10) # generated SQL has 'LIMIT 10'
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/limit

Comment: Works, made my day